# Does each repository get its own instance of hg serve?

Tags: mercurial

I am following Mercurial guide and [quickstart](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/quickstart) and don't see this called out specifically so I'd appreciate a little guidance on setting up the repos.

Let's say I have a c:\repo directory (Windows) with two project directories.

Should `hg serve` be run from each dir on different ports?

In the quickstart I see `http://selenic.com/repo/hello`.  How does that work?

Any pointers in the right direction would be great, thanks.

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955764/mercurial-localhost-site-overview-of-code-issues, my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955764/mercurial-localhost-site-overview-of-code-issues/3958351#3958351.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in this case you should run 2 instances of serve on different ports.

Look at https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/PublishingRepositories to get more advanced way to share your repositories.